# Razor create dynamic table 6 rows x columns

Tags: html, razor

I'm trying to create a table dynamically with a list of items. The table must **always** have 6 rows, but the number of columns is undefined. For example, it could be 75, or 167 items.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @{
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.mListCardSets.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i%6 == 0)
                {
                    @:<tr>
                }
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i].Name, new { @title = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                </td>
                if (i%6 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr>
                }
            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I've tried multiple other ways without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer!

Here's the solution:

```
<table id="cardSetTable" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    @{
        var divfactor = (Model.mListCardSets.Count / 6) + (Model.mListCardSets.Count % 6);

        int count = 0;

        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < divfactor; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i].Name, new { @class = "nullify", @title = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                </td>
            }
            @{
                count++;
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < divfactor; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name, new {@class = "nullify",  @title = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                </td>
            }
            @{
                count++;
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < divfactor; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name, new { @class = "nullify", @title = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                </td>
            }
            @{
                count++;
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < divfactor; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name, new { @class = "nullify", @title = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                </td>
            }
            @{
                count++;
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < divfactor; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name) 
                    @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name, new { @class = "nullify", @title = Model.mListCardSets[i + (count * divfactor)].Name })
                </td>
            }
            @{
                count++;
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @{
                var lastRow = divfactor*count;

                for (int i = lastRow; i < Model.mListCardSets.Count; i++)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Code)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkGroup4", @id = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                        @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mListCardSets[i].Name) 
                        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\CardSetRarity\\" + Model.mListCardSets[i].Code + "_R.jpeg", Model.mListCardSets[i].Name, new { @class = "nullify", @title = Model.mListCardSets[i].Name })
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```